# The application's minSdkVersion is newer than the device API level (android-R)

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio-4.0, android-11

I have a device with android version 10.

Also, I have an emulator with API 22

this is a part of my build.gradle(:app) file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    compileSdkVersion 'android-R'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.sOnline"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 'R'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
//        android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath = true
    }
}
```

It just not working on 'android-R'

Thank you for helping me :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`targetSdkVersion "R"` will restrict your app to only running on Android R, by artificially raising your `minSdkVersion` to `R`. This has been the case for the past several years: each developer preview only supports running the app on the developer preview itself, not older devices.

Sometime later this year, we will be able to switch to using `targetSdkVersion 30`, at which point normal behavior returns with respect to `minSdkVersion`.

Comment: @user1090751: I do not know what you consider "the problem" to be. If you want to experiment with `targetSdkVersion 'R'`, you can do so, but that app cannot be installed on Android 10 or older devices. So, your experiments need to be a bit separate from other work. That could be by using product flavors (one flavor for normal, one flavor for R). Or, it could be by using a separate development branch in your version control system. Or, it could be by simply making a copy of your project and experimenting with the copy.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to build.gradle file
2. in defaultConfig: change minSdk to 28 and targetSdk to 30

I use a samsung s9 plus, had the same problem and now it works

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.consigness"
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was that the virtual device was corrupted , to fix this follow these steps :

1. open the AVD manager from the top right corner.
2. delete the device from the actions menu.
3. create a new one.
4. choose the new device and run your application.

For future safety before exiting the android studio make sure to close the emulator first.